# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json

I am making a component that should transfer the data in file controllers/hello.js(backend) to App.js(frontend in React.js app) which is imported from the router/collector components/hello.js

My components/hello.js looks like this:

```js
import { React } from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


export const Hello = ()=>{
    const[initialState, setInitialState] = useState([], )

    useEffect(()=> {
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/', {mode: "no-cors"})
            .then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(JSON.parse(data)))
    //         if (res.ok){
    //             return res.json()
    //     }
    //     }).then(jsonResponse => console.log(jsonResponse))
    },[])

    // console.log(initialState)
    console.log("should work ")
    return (<div>Hello</div>)
}
```

And I get this error:

```js
        
       Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at hello.js:9:1
```

when I check the API the only response I get is this
[image]
but it should be matching what's in localhost:3001/api/ or what's in controllers/hello.js which is
[image]

Do you have any idea how I can solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if it makes it easier line 9:1 is         fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/', {mode: "no-cors"})

Comment: Could you share your server implementation please

Comment: `useState([], )` <-- why the comma?

Comment: One thing is that when you call `.json` on a response, you don't need to call `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: from MDN
Note that mode: "no-cors" only allows a limited set of headers in the request:
- Accept
- Accept-Language
- Content-Language
- Content-Type with a value of application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain